# what is the main difference between ROUGE and BLUE?

Tags: nlp, transformer, model-evaluations, language-model, llm

Both (ROUGE, BLUE) are useful to find the similarity between machine generated summary and reference summary.

what is the main difference?

Comment: You can find the answer in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38045290/674487). Please note that it is "BLEU" not "BLUE"